# Looping through multidimensional JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

am trying to display JSON data in an HTML table.

**Sample JSON Data**

```
[
    {
        "rect": [
        {
            "req": "108",
            "dev": "000",
            "pre": "201",
            "tst": "2019-08-10 18:18:10"
        },
        {
            "req": "107",
            "dev": "000",
            "pre": "210",
            "tst": "2019-08-04 22:05:31"
        },
        {
            "req": "106",
            "dev": "000",
            "pre": "299",
            "tst": "2019-08-04 20:24:40"
        },
        {
            "req": "105",
            "dev": "000",
            "pre": "210",
            "tst": "2019-08-04 20:24:29"
        },
        {
            "req": "104",
            "dev": "000",
            "pre": "290",
            "tst": "2019-08-04 20:16:07"
        },
        ],
        "ntif": {
            "notification": 6
        }
    }
]
```

and this is my JavaScript,

```
success: function(JSONObject) {
    var peopleHTML = "";


    for (var key in JSONObject) {
        if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          peopleHTML += "<tr>";
          peopleHTML += "<td>" + JSONObject["rect"][key]["req"] + "</td>";
          peopleHTML += "<td>" + JSONObject["rect"][key]["pre"] + "</td>";
          peopleHTML += "</tr>";
    }


}


    $("#people tbody").html(peopleHTML);

}
```

**Output**

[image]

When loading the page, only the first 3 objects are prased into the HTML table, rest of the data are not shown in the table.
How can I display the whole data in the table?

Comment: Why not just iterate over the inner object with the array and access the elements in this fashion -> ```JSONObject['rect'][index]['req']/['pre']```. Index is the index of the element in the array.

Comment: You are looping through the indices of the main array and using that for `rect` array. `JSONObject` array has 3 objects in it. If `rect` of each object are to be shown in the same table, you need to use a nested for loop. (Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop without `hasOwnProperty` check. `for...in` is for objects)

Comment: yeah thats great, will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double `forEach` once to iterate the outer array then inner array.

```js
let data = [{
  "rect": [{
      "req": "108",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "201",
      "tst": "2019-08-10 18:18:10"
    },
    {
      "req": "107",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "210",
      "tst": "2019-08-04 22:05:31"
    },
    {
      "req": "106",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "299",
      "tst": "2019-08-04 20:24:40"
    },
    {
      "req": "105",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "210",
      "tst": "2019-08-04 20:24:29"
    },
    {
      "req": "104",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "290",
      "tst": "2019-08-04 20:16:07"
    },
  ],
  "ntif": {
    "notification": 6
  }
}]

let peopleHTML = '';
data.forEach(function(items) {
  items.rect.forEach(function(elem) {
    peopleHTML += `<tr>
                <td>${elem.req}</td>
                <td>${elem.pre}</td>
               </tr>`
  })
})
$("#people tbody").html(peopleHTML);
```

```css
table tbody tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='people'>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate the `rect` array directly.

```js
let data = [{
  "rect": [{
      "req": "108",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "201",
      "tst": "2019-08-10 18:18:10"
    },
    {
      "req": "107",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "210",
      "tst": "2019-08-04 22:05:31"
    },
    {
      "req": "106",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "299",
      "tst": "2019-08-04 20:24:40"
    },
    {
      "req": "105",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "210",
      "tst": "2019-08-04 20:24:29"
    },
    {
      "req": "104",
      "dev": "000",
      "pre": "290",
      "tst": "2019-08-04 20:16:07"
    },
  ],
  "ntif": {
    "notification": 6
  }
}]

let peopleHTML = '';
[].forEach.call(data[0].rect, function(elem) {
  peopleHTML += `<tr>
                <td>${elem.req}</td>
                <td>${elem.pre}</td>
               </tr>`
});
$("#people tbody").html(peopleHTML);
```

```css
table tbody tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='people'>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```